# Deploy python compiled/encrypted app with heavy dependencies (numpy, PySide, pandas...)

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm wondering which you think is the best way to deploy a Python App without sending the source code. I mean, i would like to keep the source code by my side, and deploy just some 'encrypted' or 'compiled' code (.pyc, .pyd...)

My app has some important dependencies, like PySide2, pandas, numpy...
I setup my environment using pipenv.

I tried PyInstaller, but I'm having some missing dependencies errors (distutils?)

Comment: `.pyc` files are neither encrypted nor compiled. They contain a binary result of the the expensive parsing and analysing process for a source file. There are tools that can reconstruct source files from bytecode.

Comment: So .pyc files are not the way to go. Any recomendation to pack a PySide2 app? Thanks!